# MAUI App stuck in Distribution Profile after upgrading VS for Mac

Tags: ios, maui, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have a few MAUI apps that I have built using Visual Studio for Mac that I could build and debug on my phone without a problem. I recently updated Visual Studio to the latest 17.4 version. Since then the only options for debugging the iOS version my apps are the iOS version 16 simulators OR upgrading my phone to iOS 16.1. I upgraded my phone to iOS 16.1.1 and now I cannot deploy the app to my phone. The problem I am getting is that I get a message stating that my app is being deployed with a Distribution Profile even though I have the certificate and profile set to a development profile.

My biggest issue is the inability to debug my apps on the phone due to the system "thinking" that the app is signed with a distribution profile instead of the development profile that is actually being used. The secondary issue is the inability to use earlier simulators (prior to iOS 16) for testing. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I am debugging from Visual Studio from Windows, using 17.4 version, without any problems. (Set up as automatic provisioning)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Mac version 17.4

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that `XCode 14` with `iOS 16.1` is not yet supported in `.NET MAUI`. For more details, you can refer to [[Meta] Xcode 14.1 Support](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16659) and follow it up here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16659.

Thanks for your feedback and patience.

Comment: I haven't heard from you for a few days. May I confirm if there is anything else that I can help here?